# Define custom types and achieve polymorphic behaviour

Tags: typescript, types, polymorphism

I have two types of objects `save` and `exit` and another one `save-exit` which acts like both. The purpose is when I run the `exec` function below in the case of the `save-exit` object type both if blocks will be covered:

```js
const save = Symbol('save');
const exit = Symbol('exit');

type Save = typeof save;
type Exit = typeof exit;
type SaveExit = Save & Exit;
type MenuRequestType = Save | Exit | SaveExit;

function exec(val: MenuRequestType) {
    if (val === save) {
        console.log('save')
    }
    if (val === exit) {
        console.log('exit')
    }
}

let a: MenuRequestType = /* new SaveExit(); */
exec(a) // prints both save and exit
```

I also tried to do this with enums but no progress so far. Any ideas how to adjust this so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71424419/define-custom-types-and-achieve-polymorphic-behaviour/71424883?noredirect=1#comment126246107_71424883):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGA3ApjAvDAygTwLYCMQAbACgHIEUyBKAbgChRJZkAPAS1gxwOPLc40GTaHCTIAohy5Y8hUhXEBaAVCH16Aek0wAmiACuMXOwDmAC1hgQV5MgAmMKOeQRkALi06o2AA6pMcXQnP2QQADMxFAZtEP8YKU5gn38ImFUY71CscUSZFLDIyklpBkZwUXgiIgBBYCh2CuCAbWKAGnTpDuK8gF0YeAgYEShaGFiAJ2R4e3AibBhmgrT2uMLOzg7lotzpXvoCmDqG8GTQtKra+sbIZrADAmQJ3rHY7ajUAB81tNUYb-ePWkGhGA2u4AAYgYwOCwO4YAAlZCgCb2AA8xxuHRI1HQAD4YIgQOx7ASMABvegwRbFfo4mCU6nUkTEZAAOiIIFM5GK6mpAF82lTFqo6bjGUyWUR2ZzuWRVHyYILha1dpwxQzhdTnOwIKqUL0cQwmU5zLrmqKjcLlfyyuFobCwbASPBYfDMeBqPCiSTNdTXScwFCYYHmgGboa6PR+RoAyRirjYgAiYpJ+hx1SJnRJ1RpuNAzhZmAp8RJjo56RpoA)

```ts
const save = Symbol('save');
const exit = Symbol('exit');
const saveExit = Symbol('save-exit');

// You might not need these:
// type Save = typeof save;
// type Exit = typeof exit;
// type SaveExit = typeof saveExit;

const allActions = [save, exit, saveExit] as const; // readonly [typeof save, typeof exit, typeof saveExit]
type Action = typeof allActions[number]; // typeof save | typeof exit | typeof saveExit

const actionFunction: Record<Action, () => void> = {
  [save] () {
    console.log('save');
  },
  [exit] () {
    console.log('exit');
  },
  [saveExit] () {
    this[save]();
    this[exit]();
  },
};

function act (action: Action): void {
  actionFunction[action]();
}

act(save) // "save"
act(exit) // "exit"
act(saveExit) // "save", "exit"
```

Original answer:

Just create a third type to represent both:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGA3ApjAvDAygTwLYCMQAbACgHIEUyBKAbgChRJZkAPAS1gxwOPLc40GTaHCTIAohy5Y8hUhXEBaAVCH16Aek0wAmiACuMXOwDmAC1hgQV5MgAmMKOeQRkALi06o2AA6pMcXQnP2QQADMxFAZtEP8YKU5gn38ImFUY71CscUSZFLDIyklpBkZwUXgiIgBBYCh2CuCAbWKAGnTpDuK8gF0YeAgYEShaGFiAJ2R4e3AibBhmgrT2uMLOzg7lotzpXvoCmDqG8GTQtKra+sbIZrADAmQJ3rHY7ajUAB81tNUYb-ePWkGnCBjA11O8HqMBIUJOYHcRwhYGoiMQIHYjgA3vQYHAAO6cYDmGFwm7UGA4vF44CDVDFRFU6k0irEZAAOiIIFM5GK6mZePwU3gAGsGMyAL646m0twbKCM6XMkRsznc-jSfkCoXTMVKmBS5V0j55RUC4asogcrk8xRUOj6lmQVU2jWCB3mnWi8XUw0G+hS+hwkjFCmxABExXDQfqJFUYZ04dU0eDQM4CZgkfE4Y6Sek0aAA)

```ts
const save = Symbol('save');
const exit = Symbol('exit');
const saveExit = Symbol('save-exit');

// You might not need these:
// type Save = typeof save;
// type Exit = typeof exit;
// type SaveExit = typeof saveExit;

const allActions = [save, exit, saveExit] as const; // readonly [typeof save, typeof exit, typeof saveExit]
type Action = typeof allActions[number]; // typeof save | typeof exit | typeof saveExit

function act (action: Action): void {
  switch (action) {
    case save: {
      console.log('save');
      break;
    }
    case exit: {
      console.log('exit');
      break;
    }
    case saveExit: {
      console.log('save');
      console.log('exit');
      break;
    }
  }
}

act(save) // "save"
act(exit) // "exit"
act(saveExit) // "save", "exit"
```

Comment: Some people don't like `switch`. If you're in that category, that's fine: just create an object with the symbol actions as keys, and the associated functions as values, then invoke the key on the object based on the action parameter.

Comment: That would probably get closer to a solution since I'm trying to avoid the `saveExit` case in your answer (duplicate code)

Comment: @AndreiRoba See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though not a perfect solution I'm actually looking for something like this:

```js
const save = Symbol('save');
const exit = Symbol('exit');

const Save = { [save]: true };
const Exit = { [exit]: true };
const SaveExit = { [save]: true, [exit]: true };
type ActionType = typeof Save | typeof Exit | typeof SaveExit;

function exec(val: ActionType) {
    if (save in val) {
        console.log('save')
    }
    if (exit in val) {
        console.log('exit')
    }
}

let a: ActionType = SaveExit;
exec(a) // prints both save and exit
```

any other more elegant solutions/improvements are highly welcome!